# Using link variables in an array to create clean URLs in PHP?

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

In my php script, I have written code to pull out the url variables and to store them in an array 
For eg: if my url is 
www/viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Fall&pcaption=Light-On-Dunes

Then in my array 'path_info' I have

```
$path_info[base] = /
$path_info[query_var][cname] = Colorado-Fall
$path_info[query_var][pcaption] = Light-on-Dunes
```

etc

Now, How can I use this array to make clean urls in my php code?

If I try to write the link as

```
<a href = viewgallery.php/$path_info[query_var][cname]/$path_info[query_var][pcaption]></a>
```

it won't take me to the requested page.
Ultimately, I want the url in my address bar to look as

> www/viewgallery.php/Colorado-Fall/Light-On-Dunes

How can I make this link work with my php script?
I know I can do this with .htaccess but is it possible to do it just with my php script using my array variables?

Comment: .htaccess would be better suited to this

Comment: Vector ...is .htaccess the only way to do this? Can this be done in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
echo "<a href='viewgallery.php/{$path_info[query_var][cname]}/{$path_info[query_var][pcaption]}'></a>";
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, That makes the url in the required format in the address  bar eg: www/viewgallery.php/Colorado-Fall/Light-On-Dunes. But the link won't work meaning it won't take me to that image.:(

Answer (score 0):

In your link you have written it as `html`. You should write it as `php`

```
<a href ="viewgallery.php/<?php echo "$path_info[query_var][cname]/$path_info[query_var][pcaption]"?>"></a>
```

and also remember to use quote marks on the `a` tag